# How to make a D flip flop circuit that pulses 4 times per switch toggle?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, quartus

For a [school project](https://deproject.tiiny.site/) we must design an ALU and its control circuit (see schematic).

[image: ALU Circuit]

As part of the controller, we must make a circuit that clocks our registers (one is PISO, the other SIPO). The registers can be seen below (registers A  and B, respectively).

[image: A Register]

[image: B Register]

The issue we are having is our controller is logically correct, providing 4 clock pulses when load is toggled. When a timing simulation is ran it shows that our clock enabler is actually pulsing 5 times. The clock schematic can be seen below.

[image: Clock Enabler Circuit]

Below are the functional and timing simulations, respectively.

[image: Functional Clock Simulation]

[image: Timing Clock Simulation]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site and great to see you working on a project driving learning :-) Make sure you never gate clocks - connect all clock inputs directly to the single logic clock. The FPGA/CPLD manufacturers provide the D-type Flip-Flop with Enable (DFFE) for what you're doing there. Conditional logic drives DFFE's Enable input and if high, DFFE acts on its next clock. May fix your problem but does need doing. Gating clocks creates all sorts of problems and is a major no, you'll find plenty of detail on internet. (It can be done, eg in ASICs, but its rarely necessary in FPGA/CPLD.)

Comment: Nick, do you want the four clocks to be triggered by the falling edge of the switch input? It looks that way. But i want to be sure. I'm assuming the switch is operated manually, is already debounced elsewhere, but the edges are otherwise completely asynchronous to the clocking source in the top display curve. Also, does there always need to be at least one missing pulse at a minimum between the groups of four? A quick skim is leaving me with questions. I'm sorry about that. And I don't want to suss out some of the answers by scrutinizing schematics.

Comment: Falling edge, correct @jonk. The pulses don’t need to be synchronous with the clicking source. And realistically there does need to be a pause in between the 4 clock pulses, but unless the user can toggle a switch at 1 KHz it should work. I know the switch we were using wasn’t debounced itself, however I thought we had accounted for it elsewhere. I’ll look into that.

Comment: @NickLybarger Okay. More questions. If they don't need to be synchronous, does their period need to be twice as long as the clocking source as appears in the pictures? I sure took the impression that you need that from the pictures *and* the implications from text. And if they must be twice the period (half the frequency) but can be asynchronous, what would be the "meaning?" It's just an unknown phase shift. Why not have a known range for the phase shift? I think I understand the purpose. (Or I thought I did, having built my own from 7400 series parts in 1974.)

Comment: @NickLybarger (What I used back in the day was a spring-loaded toggle for a single-step operation.)

Comment: @NickLybarger Your web link to the project is broken.

Comment: The most obvious thing I'd try is to rerun your simulation, but bring out the common preset and clear lines, to see how they are behaving. Additionally, you haven't provided the propagation times for either the gates or flipflops. Since you're operating at a 20 nsec cycle time, and your reset line is given by a signal delayed by one FF and two gate propagation delays, I'd look to that issue first. Using a FF output to reset the FF is VERY bad practice, although the two gate delays improve the situation considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can't easily write the following in commentary. So I'm adding it as an answer here. I may expand on this, should you add more detail, and attempt something that is closer to what you want. But in the meantime, this will be more my hope that it helps a little and perhaps encourages the addition of more information to your question.*

### Debouncing a manual momentary SPST

Jack Ganssle has long since prepared a white paper on analog debouncing of manual switches. And my own experience predates his first edition by 15 years, at least. You can review his writing [here](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm) and [here](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm).

Max Maxfield also has written extensively. He wrote these 9 parts to his **Ultimate Guide to Switch Debounce**:

1. [Fundamental Concepts](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-1/)
2. [Deep Dive into SPST and SPDT Switches](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-2/)
3. [Debouncing with RC networks](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-3/)
4. [Debouncing with Multivibrators](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-4/)
5. [Debouncing with Latches](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-5/)
6. [Specialized Switch Debounce ICs](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-6/)
7. [Switches as Resets and Interrupts and Polling vs. Interrupt-Driven](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-7/)
8. [FPGA and MCU Solutions](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-8/)
9. [Software Solutions](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-9/)

When I was first learning how to do it, articles I read talked about using a "*one-shot*," using either the 74121 or 74122 as canonical cases. However, I settled on the examples I read about that used an SPDT, instead, together with an SR. That seemed to work pretty well for me and it's what the *professionals* did in the mid-1960s for front panels on computers, many supporting manual single-stepping, before I got involved about a decade later on. This required a slightly more complicated switch. But back then they were just as commonly available as an SPST version and also about the same price.

Should I continue writing towards a fuller answer, I'm going to assume that you have a debounced momentary SPST of some kind that is operated manually. So its rising and falling edges will be entirely asynchronous to the clock. (Completely independent of it.) But satisfactory to your application. (And, as I understand you, you want to apply the falling edge [assuming active-high, of course] as the trigger for the pulse sequencing.)

### Other assumptions

If I continue writing towards a fuller answer:

- I'm going to assume that what you are looking for is to produce exactly four cycles at half the clock frequency (8 clock periods.)
- I'm going to assume that you require at least one additional missing cycle (at half the clock frequency) before another group of four can be produced.
- And I'm NOT going to worry about the fact that you dealing with a \$50\:\text{MHz}\$ clock. If there are logic delays that cause problems, or if variability in those logic delays that aren't under control may cause still more trouble, or if there may be metastability issues with the flip-flops used, then that's your problem to worry about.
- Finally, I'm assuming that your purpose here is for **single-stepping** your ALU, *manually*. If this is wrong, you need to say so.

If the above is correct, you write enough, and I find the time I'm going to focus only on the sequential/combinatorial logic design.

You can work out the rest.

### Notes

You may want to read [this slide show by Ryan Donohue](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee183/handouts/synchronization_pres.pdf) on the topic of bringing an asynchronous signal into a clock chain using synchronizers. I don't think it is critical just when a manual switch is recognized. I think the focus is, as you write, on generating the desired pulse chain (with gap) when a manual switch is applied. But you've not written enough for me to be sure. So I am, admittedly, doing some guessing.